# Name that thing... Circular 4-pin female connector

Tags: connector, identification

I've been asked to wire in some Octopod LED lights driven by a Pixel Drive 30 controller, but I can't work out what the connectors are between the lights.  I tried to contact the manufacturer but they've been taken over and the person I dealt with wasn't able to tell me.  This is one of the connectors I have...

[image: end view] [image: side view]

Specifications are:-

- 4 equidistantly arranged pins
- 12mm diameter across the plastic part (I assume to fit a 1/2" male part?)
- 9mm depth to collar
- Screw-fit casing

My behringher mx1602 mixing desk power supply has a similar connector in a 3-pin configuration.

From looking around it seemed to be an "Amphenol" connector used in vintage microphones and also power supplies.  My searches so far have been contradictory that the parts are rare as hen's teeth and very expensive but that doesn't fit with the use of a 3-pin variant in a relatively 'budget' piece of equipment like the MX1602.

My searches for Amphenol seem to be a company that make an awful lot of connectors but I haven't been able to identify which model/part/description this part is in order to be able to even try to order one.

Comment: A side view may help.

Comment: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/4-Pin-Round-Microphone-Connector-for-Kenwood-Icom-Yaesu-Alinco-2-ship-any-qty-/161427286295?pt=US_Ham_Radio_Transceivers&hash=item2595d0e917, it's a similar one.

Comment: Looks similar to amphenol 91-mc4m series (opposite sex).

Comment: Possible datasheet for another version out of japan http://www.philmore-datak.com/mc/Page%2054.pdf

Comment: Have a look [here:](https://www.google.com/search?q=microphone+connector&espv=2&biw=1137&bih=783&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=WgiDVLTEKoGsyATjooGYBw&ved=0CF4Q7Ak&dpr=0.9)

Comment: My Yamaha mixing desk uses one for the 12V AC power feed in.

Comment: Hm, this looks exactly like the  Mc Voice soldering station connectors... and somehwere I think I read a question trying to identify these kind of connectors by I failed to find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This maybe a not very precise description:

> 4 Pin Female Inline Microphone Connector: These circular connectors are
>   most commonly used for microphones, but they are rugged, multi-pin
>   connectors suitable for a wide variety of uses. Each connector is
>   keyed to ensure proper polarity. They provide a threaded locking ring
>   for reliable contact under extreme shock and vibration. These
>   connectors are great for mobile use and can handle both voice, data
>   and power applications. Includes a built in strain relief

According to

1. http://www.vetco.net/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=6552
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone_connector

Comment: My father's ham radio had one - Kenwood TS120. The microphone connected to one of these jacks. The microphone also included a push-to-talk switch. Since only 3 pins are needed for these things the fourth may have been an optional/unused speaker output.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a GX12-4 connector, mostly available through eBay.  I've ordered some myself and hope they are the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

That is an Amphenol 91-MC4F(female). The partner to that is the 91-MC4M(male). I have found them, but they ARE expensive now!